# Can't display Interstitial Ad for first time user only

Tags: android, admob

I want to show an **Interstitial Ad** to a user who has downloaded the app for the first time **only.** This will show only once.

I have written code to determine if the user is a first time user. - Which is working fine.

### ISSUE / ERORR

My **displayInterstitial()** method is returning **AD IS NOT LOADED**? - **interstitial.isLoaded()** is false hence **interstitial.show(**) does not get called.

### MY UNDERSTANDING

I have **loadAd()** in the oncreate, so the **displayInterstitial()** should work in this case. But it doesn't.

### CODE

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inbox_list);
       createAdmobBanner();
        
        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxx/xxx");
     
        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequestIN = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequestIN);
         
          //CHECK IF USER DOWNLOADED APP FOR FIRST TIME.
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {
            //the app is being launched for first time, do something        
            Log.d("Comments", "First time");
              //CALL LARGE SCREEN ADD
              displayInterstitial();

            // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
            settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit(); 
        }

   // Set an AdListener.
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
          
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Proceed to the next level.
            

            // Create ad request.
            AdRequest adRequestIN = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

            // Begin loading your interstitial.
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequestIN);
        }
    });


    //SHOW ADD 
    public void displayInterstitial() 
    {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) 
        {
           interstitial.show();
           Log.d("response", "AD IS LOADED: ");
        }
    else 
       {
              Log.d("response", "AD IS NOT LOADED: "  );
       }
       }
```

Comment: You answered your own question: `My displayInterstitial() method is returning AD IS NOT LOADED? - interstitial.isLoaded() is`. The ad is not ready yet. Look into using the `Ad Listeners`.

Comment: eeep thanks, I see i'm getting 08-05 22:13:42.693: I/Ads(10822): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
08-05 22:13:42.698: I/Ads(10822): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
There must be some kind of AdLoading() method i assume. thanks Jared

Comment: Yes, look at the ad listeners.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AdMob interstitial ad not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953046/admob-interstitial-ad-not-loading)

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that's a duplicate, it's not very useless for this case

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `displayInterstitial()` before an ad has been loaded.
Interstitial ads take some time to load.

You are trying to display it too early.